# Cython cannot declare None type

Tags: cython

I have a .pyx file as follow :

```
cdef class Foo:
    def __cinit__(self, bar=None):
        self.bar = bar
```

and a .pxd as follow :

```
cdef class Foo:
    cdef public ??? bar
```

Instead of `???` I would like to declare the type to be either `int` or `None`

I tried using a fusedtype with void or int, which does not work either.

Does anyone know how to make it compile? Using `None` or `Null`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main purpose of Python types is to define an efficient C representation (in space used or speed). `int` is understood by Python to mean a C integer, and there is no C datatype which could either be a C integer or a Python `None` object.

You then have two options:

1. Make `bar` a Python object (`cdef public object bar`) and add some runtime type checks in the constructor to ensure that it is either an integer or `None`. You might want to use `@property` to also check it when written to. Since this uses Python objects you should not expect any Cython speedup.
2. Make `bar` an `int` (i.e. a C integer) and pick some special value which will represent an invalid value (and so you need to pick a value you'll never need to represent). This will be efficient in terms of space and possible speed.

Comment: I used the second option as a workaround.
And I did not think about the first one, is this a good practice? Or something we should avoid?
Thanks for you answer :)

Comment: It depends why you're doing it. I'd only use the second option if you want the benefits of the C datatype. If you only want to enforce a type I'd use the first option as having clearer intent (you can give a helpful error message, and you don't have to pick an arbitrary wrong value).